# finding distance between two object of an image with euclidean distance and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, euclidean-distance

here i have a code from [pyimagesearch](https://pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/04/measuring-distance-between-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/)
with result like [image: this]

the question is, how to finding the distance from only one countur point to other tl,tr,bl,br in other objects [image: like this?]

i'm try to edit from the code to be like exact the image im provide, but didn't work out.

Comment: OpenCV only started at the top left corner.

Comment: that's what i meant, top left corner in object A to 4 others corners in object B.

Comment: but, idk how to make that work honestly. cuz my professor(?) want exactly like that picture he provide.

Comment: I can only do w/out argparse. I do some work around.

Comment: can you help me for that?

Comment: I'm not available online right now.

Comment: tell me if you are ready...